# Проблема при загрузке .css

Tags: css, bootstrap, google-chrome, angular-cli

Файл .css почему-то не подгружается, выводя в консоли ошибку:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, заранее спасибо!
[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Ссылка на файл "bootstrap.min.css":
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij4v7pchuksannc/bootstrap.min.css?dl=0

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: сделал так - <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" />, все равно не работает

Comment: Изменил на такую строку    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />     не работает.

Comment: Убрал, не помогло(

Comment: Попробовал этот же стиль в папку с файлом index.html переместить, не работает...попробовал подключить другой файл стилей, тоже не работает

Comment: Закиньте файл в папку assets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему проект на Angular2+ и после компеляции нет доступа к папке Node Modules, а вместо файла возврящяеться текстовая страница. Попробуйте подключить этот файл в ./src/styles.css

```
 @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

~ - это маска для пути к node_modules, webpack расшифрует и подставит нужный файл в сборку Angular.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Лучшее спасибо, пометьте решение ответом

Answer (score 0):

Возможная проблема в том, что в файле css могут быть комментарии, но программа считает, что это некорректный формат для css. Уберите комментарии из css и проверьте. Возможно нужно убрать комментарии только из начала файла.

Если причина не в этом, то было бы неплохо предоставить содержимое файла css.

Comment: убрал комментарии, не помогло